# Binding a datagridview to an access table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, bind

I work with VB.net 2010. I have in my form a datagridview which gets data from an Access table. Here is the code that creates the link :

```
  CS = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & FileNewName & ";Jet OLEDB:Database        Password=asd"
  Con.ConnectionString = CS
  Con.Open()

  Da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * from tblDetail where NoCompte = " & N.ToString, Con)
  Da.Fill(tblDet)

  DataGr.DataSource = tblDet
```

All this works perfectly well. All my data from my Access table is displayed in my Datagridview.

Then the user will make changes and I want of course the new data to be updated back to the Access table.

Isn't there a short way to do this or do I have to go line by line and use an OleDbCommand with SQL saying "update tblDetail set Name = ....."

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

You use the same data adapter to save the changes as you used to retrieve the data.  `Fill` executes the `SelectCommand` and `Update` executes the `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` as required.

Comment: Good start. You might want to mention `OleDbCommandBuilder` too.